# Multiple UNION returning messy results

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm doing a homework and I currently, I have three tables.

```
[veiculos]
-placa (PK)
-categoria
-categoria_valor
-cor
-ano

[infracao]
-placa (PK)
-codigo
-descricao
-valor
-umt
-data
-hora
-local

[proprietario]
-placa (PK)
-nome
-endereco
```

I must perform a SQL query to result `placa, nome, endereco, codigo, descricao, valor, umt, data, hora, local, categoria, categoria_valor, cor, ano`

I'm using this:

```
SELECT placa, null AS nome, null AS endereco, codigo, descricao, data, hora, local, valor, umt FROM infracao WHERE (placa=[@PLACA]) 
UNION 
SELECT null AS placa, nome, endereco, null, null, null, null, null AS tipo, null, null  FROM proprietario WHERE (placa=[@PLACA])
UNION 
SELECT null, null, null, null, null, null, categoria AS tipo, categoria_valor, cor, ano FROM veiculos WHERE (placa=[@PLACA])
```

;

And the result is messy, it must return on single column but is using three columns, as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/82mAf.png

How can I solve it? Can you help me? I'm using MS Access 2013

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you joining using `UNION`? why not use a `JOIN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use subquery and max()

```
   select
   max(placa) as laca,
   max(nome) as nome,
   max(endereco) as endereco,
   max(codigo) as codigo,
   max(descricao) as descricao,
   max(data) as data,
   max(hora) as hora,max(local) as local,max(valor) as valor,
   max(umt) as umt from

     (SELECT placa, null AS nome, null AS endereco, codigo, descricao, data, hora, local, valor, umt FROM infracao WHERE (placa=[@PLACA]) 
        UNION 
        SELECT null AS placa, nome, endereco, null, null, null, null, null AS tipo, null, null  FROM proprietario WHERE (placa=[@PLACA])
        UNION 
        SELECT null, null, null, null, null, null, categoria AS tipo, categoria_valor, cor, ano FROM veiculos WHERE (placa=[@PLACA])
    ) a
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working with only one line as expected, but table name is showing something like "Expr(num)" as you can see here: http://prntscr.com/nf5nke 
Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @bilb0k edited answer actually u need to use alias of column btw if it helps mark as accepted

Comment: Hello, I'm getting this error now: `circular reference caused by alias laca`

Comment: It started working after changing all alias name. Thank you!